# How to create a VIEW in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, view

I have a user table and I need to create a VIEW so a user can only see their own data/row.

How could I achieve this? I have been searching online on how to create views but I can't find anything useful/explains well!! Please help!!

`tUser` with `user_id, name, address`

Comment: What do you mean with view? Do you want to display everything in a table via php or something simmular?

Comment: @RobinR I need to do this in SQL

Answer (score 2):

Only with having a field for user (id or name) you can make a view so that a user can see or manipulate only his/her data:

assuming your table is:

```
tbl (fld_1, usr,....) -- usr is for the the user who created the record
```

you can create your view as:

```
create view vw as
select * from tbl
where usr=current_user
```

Comment: This answers your question.  If you have some other question about stored procedures (which doesn't seem relevant), then you should ask that as *another* question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create View As VeiwDemo
Select * 
From Your_TableName
Where UserId=UserId
```